# Access props from a closure function within a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a very simple React App create using create-react-app. The app displays a single component passing in a `value` and an `onClick` callback and incrementshe value when the callback is triggered.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Block from './Block';

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Block
        value={count}
        onClick={ () => setCount(count + 1) }
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The Block component takes a `value` and a `onClick` function and displays a square with the value in the centre and calls the `onClick` whenever the square is clicked.

```
const Block = ({ value, onClick }) => {
    return (
        <div
            onClick={onClick}
            style={{
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                margin: 50,
                background: 'yellow',
                display: 'flex',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                fontSize: 36,
            }}
        >
            {value}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Block;
```

This works excatly as described.

I have then extended this component to log the value on a `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event by adding the relevent event handlers in a `useEffect` hook called when the component mounts.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';


const Block = ({ value, onClick }) => {
    const divRef = useRef();

    const mouseEnter = () => {
        console.log('mouse enter', value);
    }

    const mouseLeave = () => {
        console.log('mouse leave', value);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('addEventListeners');
        divRef.current.addEventListener('mouseenter', mouseEnter);
        divRef.current.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseLeave);
    }, [])

    return (
        <div
            ref={divRef}
            onClick={onClick}
            style={{
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                margin: 50,
                background: 'yellow',
                display: 'flex',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                fontSize: 36,
            }}
        >
            {value}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Block;
```

The problem that I am having is that the two event handlers are closures so always print the value as it was when the component was mounted. I could rewrite the component as a class component and access the props via *this* but nothing else in the project uses class components. I could copy the value to a global variable but that would restrict me to a single instance.

What is the recommended way of accessing one or more props within a closure?

I should add that this was written to demonstrate the problem. In my app the value is a large object passed in and the div is a canvas with the data plotted onto it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use React synthetic events and remove the `useEffect`:

```
  return <div onMouseEnter={mouseEnter} onMouseLeave={mouseLeave} ... />
```

Comment: I thought about it, but did not answer this since OP says that the example is made for the purpose of an example. I assumed he knew about those

Comment: Actually, I didn't know that using synthetic events would solve my problem. I did say that in the full app the div was a canvas and the synthetic events work with that.

Answer (score 1):

I would make the `mouseEnter` and `mouseLeave` functions created by the `useCallback` hook, having `value` as a dependency. The `useEffect` would then have those two functions as dependencies too.

Then, you can use the fact that the return function of useEffect is executed when dependencies are changed, just before the new `useEffect` is called. Now in the returned function just remove the listeners, so that there are always only two listeners.

It would look like something like this:

```
   const mouseEnter = useCallback(() => {
        console.log('mouse enter', value);
    }, [value]);

    const mouseLeave = useCallback(() => {
        console.log('mouse leave', value);
    }, [value]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('addEventListeners');
        divRef.current.addEventListener('mouseenter', mouseEnter);
        divRef.current.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseLeave);
        return () => {
            divRef.current.removeEventListener('mouseenter', mouseEnter);
            divRef.current.removeEventListener('mouseenter', mouseEnter);
        };
    }, [mouseEnter, mouseLeave])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add MouseEnetr and MouseLeave events to div element, you can very well achieve that as shown below. No need of any refs.

```
  return (
      <div
         onClick={() => setValue(value + 1)}
         onMouseEnter={() => mouseEnter(value)}
         onMouseLeave={() => mouseLeave(value)}
          style={{
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              margin: 50,
              background: 'yellow',
              display: 'flex',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              fontSize: 36,
          }}
      >
         {value} 
      </div>
```

If you are exploring the same by using ref then, as I know, This can be achieved as shown below.

```
  useEffect(() => {
      console.log('addEventListeners');
      // Remove listeners
      divRef.current.removeEventListener('mouseenter', mouseEnter);
      divRef.current.removeEventListener('mouseleave', mouseLeave);

      // Add listeners
      divRef.current.addEventListener('mouseenter', mouseEnter);
      divRef.current.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseLeave);
  }, [value]) // Pass value as argument, then it behaves as componentDidUpdate
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `useRef`

```
const countRef = React.useRef(count);
```

Replace `setCount` by

```
setCountRef = (value) => {
    countRef.current = value;
    setCount(value);
}
```

And then

```
const mouseLeave = () => {
    console.log('mouse leave', countRef.current);
}
```

Comment: You should not use `useRef` for state variables, use `useState` as much as possible, plus the fact the problem can be solved by another method.

Comment: @Yooooomi why exactly? What problem does it cause?

Comment: I think that is the purpose of the `useCallback` and `useEffect` dependencies, it's to update the function content when the variables change, It will work but might not be the cleanest imo, plus the fact that you will have to carry a `useEffect` around to update the ref value whenever the prop value changes

Comment: Well thanks, I'm not really familiar with `useCallback`. And no you don't have to carry around a `useEffect` since it replaces the old `setValue` with a new one that both sets the ref and the value.